# Does every group grow either polynomially or superpolynomially?

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I am reading [an introduction to growth of groups](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607384). The notions of polynomial and superpolynomial growth are introduced, as are exponential and subexponential growth.

I can prove that the growth of a group is always either exponential or subexponential (it is exercise 1.6). However, there seems to be no mention of an analogous result for (super)polynomial growth (i.e. the growth of a group is always either polynomial or superpolynomial).

There exist strictly increasing functions which grow faster than polynomially but are not superpolynomial (this is pretty clear; a more detailed explanation can be found in the second section of [this document](http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.0599v1)), but I do not know whether these occur as the growth function of some group.

[The thesis of a Nick Scott](http://www.ms.unimelb.edu.au/publications/ScottNick.pdf) claims to prove that every group grows either polynomially or superpolynomially, but I don't see it (it is in subsection 1.4.1, on p.12; it seems to me the proof assumes that the limit $\log(\beta(k))/\log(k)$ exists, but I don't know why).

So my question is: **does every group grow either polynomially or superpolynomially?**

Comment: I would suggest posting this question on [Math Overflow](http://mathoverflow.net/).

Comment: I [posted the question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/95207/does-every-group-grow-either-polynomially-or-superpolynomially) on Math Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question [has been answered on Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95207/does-every-group-grow-either-polynomially-or-superpolynomially). The answer is *yes*, by the way.

Comment: You might as well accept your answer as well to show that this question has now been dealt with.